# How to make two way binding between angular directives without using "dots"

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Suppose, I have controller:

```
angular.module('tf').controller('Ctrl', function($scope){
 $scope.params = {
     orderBy: null
 };});
```

And a directive "common":

```
 angular.module('tf').directive("common", function() {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    template: '<div><outer order-by="orderBy"><inner order-by-field="name1"></inner><inner order-by-field="name2"></inner></outer></div>',

    controller: function ($scope) {
    },

    scope: {
        orderBy: '='
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
    }
}});
```

Controller is using directive within it's template:

```
<div ng-app="tf">
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <common order-by="params.orderBy"></common>
    <div style="color:red">{{params.orderBy}}</div>
</div>
```

This directive is using directive "outer":

```
angular.module('tf').directive("outer", function() {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    replace: true,
    template: '<div ng-transclude></div>',
    controller: function ($scope) {

        this.order = function (by) {
            $scope.orderBy = by
        };
    },
    scope: {
        orderBy: '=',
    }
}});
```

Which is parent for the directive "inner":

```
angular.module('tf').directive("inner", function() {
return {
    require: '^outer',
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    replace: true,
    template: '<div ng-click="onClicked()">{{orderByField}}</div>',
    controller: function ($scope) {
        $scope.onClicked = function () {
            $scope.outer.order($scope.orderByField);
        }
    },
    scope: {
        orderByField: '@'
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, outer) {
        scope.outer = outer;
    }
}});
```

The directive "outer" shares "order" method with directive "inner" by it's controller. The directive "inner" is accessing it by using "require" mechanism.

For some reason, this is not working as expected (Property of the controller isn't updated each time it's changed by directive). If I place "orderBy" into object (e.g. {"order": {"by": null }} ) and use object instead of string value, everything is working as expected ( controller scope is properly updated by the directive). I know about "always use dots" best practices principle, but I don't wanna use it here, because it would make my directive's API less intuitive.

Here is jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/A8Vgk/1254/

Thanks

Comment: What exactly is "not working as expected"?

Comment: Property of the controller isn't updated. If you try to click on "name1", or "name2" in the jsfiddle, only second click would cause change in controller's scope.

Comment: @Lastik, change to a newer version of Angular - this was fixed, I think

Comment: @Claies Could you please explain me, why prototypical inheritance? I don't get it. Each directive has it's own isolated scope. What is inherited?

Comment: as @NewDev Stated, updating your fiddle to 1.3.14 resolves the issue completely.